# IOS Swift: How to extend scrollview and execute new process when user reach scroll bottom?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make infinite Scrollview in my photo display app by swift code.
I could find Object-c approach like "scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate" to enable this but not for swift. Here is my code where I try to use "scrollView.contentOffset.y" but not work. Could anyone help to achieve this?
I also created UIScrollView in storyboard.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
    scrollView.directionalLockEnabled = true
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
    scrollView.bounces = true
    scrollView.scrollsToTop = false
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(620, 480*3);
            self.navigationItem.titleView = pageControl

    let imgarray2 = ["1446420031.jpg", "4500129.jpg", 475323.jpg"]

    for (index, value) in enumerate(imgarray2) {
        var setx = 0
        var sety = index*480
        var imgnum = index+1
        let url = NSURL.URLWithString("\(value)");
        var err: NSError?
        var imageData :NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(url,options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &err)
        var blueimage = UIImage(data:imageData)
        var blueView = UIImageView(image: blueimage)
        blueView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        blueView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: setx, y: sety), size:blueimage.size)
        scrollView.addSubview(blueView)
    }

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)) {
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(620, 480*6);
        for (index, value) in enumerate(imgarray2) {
            var setx = 0
            var sety = index*480+(480*3)
            var imgnum = index+1
            let url = NSURL.URLWithString("\(value)");
            var err: NSError?
            var imageData :NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(url,options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &err)
            var blueimage = UIImage(data:imageData)
            var blueView = UIImageView(image: blueimage)
            blueView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
            blueView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: setx, y: sety), size:blueimage.size)
            scrollView.addSubview(blueView)
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's a Swift version of scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:, is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, could you advise how to write in swift or where to learn it? thank you.

Comment: You know how to use UIScrollViewDelegate in Objective-C, right? If so, info about converting Objective-C to Swift can be found here - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_25.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. I will learn from this.